# How to isolate Actor data model

Tags: scala, design-patterns, command, akka, actor

I'm

in the process of transforming the architecture of my system, which at the level i am interested in, is not multi-threaded for now.

Let say today i have a component A that communicate with a component B via a command pattern to isolate one another from each other. So as we all know only the command actually bridge them. The Good thing is only the command implementation has to change if one of the component implementation has to change. In my situation component B will evolve over time.

> I was wondering how to replicate that with Akka Actor. Indeed i
>   believe with actors, indeed command do not have the right to
>   manipulate the content of an actor or whatever the actor encapsulate.
>
> So i would like to know how should this pattern be change to meet
>   actor requirement.

In my particular case, my command contains data from A that based on the nature of the command trigger the creation of Data in B following its data model.

> Just to give a clue: B is a component that wrap a semantic database.
>   In A we have some java object. It is not their representation as is
>   that has to be entered in B.  Think of it like you have a language (we
>   represent with object the sentences that you can form with it) and its
>   semantic that we represent with triples. A is a component that observe
>   message (in that language) and trigger the command that create the
>   appropriate semantic in B. B does some reasoning with this semantic
>   and monitor it over time.

(This is a gross simplification but it is just to give a context)

PS:

I'm new in the Actor field.

Comment: Don't do *commands*, do *events*. Instead of Alice making Bob give her all of his money (in other words robbing him), she can kindly ask Bob for a favor.

Comment: Could you elaborate further especially in the context of the semantic that I talk about. Shall I create a specific data model to communicate between the two actor that will be independent of their two respective data model

Comment: I want to isolate them from their respective implementation. I don't a to be aware of the implementation of b and vice versa